# Using Ajax to change the color of a button when the corresponding button is pressed from another computer

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, ajax

what im doing is writing a program for myself to use in my community theater. we will have a computer in the control room (Sound Booth) and a computer backstage.

I am making a grid of say 10 "buttons" on the screen (more likely styled  tags). there will be text in the buttons like "Mic 1 Battery Change" and it will be a muted gray color:

```
    <a class="g">TEXT</a>
```

the desired goal is that if control room hits a button the button should turn red:

```
    <a class="r">TEXT</a>
```

this should change both on the control room computer and on the one backstage, and when the person back stage clicks the button again (while its red), it reverts back to gray in both locations to let control know that the task has been completed.

I cant imagine this is difficult to accomplish with a database and ajax, however im really less than a novice with ajax so i don't know the best approach. if someone could either point me to a tutorial for something i can adapt to this fairly easily or if someone who knows how to do this could write me some simple code for this kind of thing and explain it. that would be awesome.

Comment: this text is very hard to read

Comment: ok i edited. hopefully this makes more sense now :P

Comment: Is your objective is to write software for this as a learning exercise or to solve a problem with a piece of software? If you just need a tool to communicate I suggest a shared google doc or trello board to accomplish this. If you want to learn how to write software I would start with CodeAcademy and work up to a problem like this.

Comment: essentially learning as well as function. i have a few people bugging me constantly about it since i offered to give it a try and they arent letting up with the daily nagging at me. normally following those learning things doesnt help me. i learn best by following tutorials for many of the common functions applied to multiple uses etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could be polling an activity table that does the call every x seconds via JQuery to a PHP script which reads from the activity table, and by doing so you would detect whether the user pressed a button or not. An easy way to do it would be like this:
User presses a button -> You send the activity to the activity table with a timestamp, so you know when the user pressed the button (we'll get to this later).
You could send it by doing a post to PHP via JQuery and then inserting it on a database.
The activity table would contain:
id (INT), primary, auto_increment.
button (INT) [The button id that was clicked]
dateposted [timestamp]
Now, every time you poll that table / call that table by using JQuery and PHP, you would be polling the time (important) and the button id, which I often do like so:

Client Side: (You could have a different ID for each button like so)

```
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function reloadstring()
    {
            $.get("checknewactivity.php", function(buttonid){
            if (buttonid == 1) /* Say he clicked the record button for example */
            {
               $("#recordbtn").css({"background-color":"#FF0000"}); /* Make the record button red */
            }
            });
    }, 1000); // refresh every 1000 milliseconds
/* And this would poll every 1 second as it says above */
```

Server side: (checkactivity.php)

```
<?php
    checkactivity();
    function checkactivity() {

        $querystats = "SELECT activity.id, activity.buttonid, activity.dateposted FROM activity ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
        $resultstats = mysqli_query($yourdbhandle,$querystats);
        $num_stats = mysqli_num_rows($resultstats);
        $rowactivity = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultstats);

        if($num_stats > 0) { /* If there was activity */

            $activity_id = $rowactivity["id"];
                $activity_date = $rowactivity["dateposted"]; //I can't indent this here for some reason.
            $activity_buttonid = $rowactivity["buttonid"];
            $timeactivity = strtotime( "$activity_date" );
            $actualtime = time(); //The actual time in a timestamp
            $timetoseconds = $actualtime - $timeactivity; //Actual time - timeactivity

            if($timetoseconds < 6) { /* If the last activity was sent less than 6 seconds ago */
                echo "$activity_buttonid"; //This would send the last clicked button id
            }
        }                       
    }
?>
```

This is not the best way to do it, but an easy way instead, the best way to do it would be by using webSockets or node.JS to avoid polling the database over and over and only send results to the client once the server finds an update. This is a draft, and a brief explanation on how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the great response! :D just want to make sure i have this right. with this setup my HTML wopuld be as simple as:

`<button id="recordbtn">Mic One Battery is dead</button>`

correct?

Comment: Yes, you would do it like that.

Comment: so for each button would i need to repeat the whole thing like so?:
`$.get("checknewactivity.php", function(buttonid){
            if (buttonid == 1) /* Say he clicked the record button for example */
            {
               $("#recordbtn2...3..4. etc").css({"background-color":"#FF0000"}); /* Make the record button red */
            }
            });`
Sorry for all the noob questions with this but i very much appreciate your input

Comment: Nope, you would give an id to each button let's say and a class for each if you want. Then, once you click that button in that certain class, you would get the button id and send it to the activity table. You would then poll that activity table and color the button like I explained above.
Under `if(buttonid == 1) { }` you would put `if(buttonid == 2) { }` and so on.. It's too repetitive so I would find a better way to solve it, but that actually works.

Comment: so does eact button get id="recordbutton"? or id="2" etc.

Comment: The numbers themselves are invented by you and then sent to the database depending on what button you've clicked. I'm using id's but you could instead set the buttonid to varchar and just sent the button id from there and then read it off with JQuery as I explained you above. Like so:
`function(buttonid){ $("#" + buttonid).css({"background-color":"#FF0000"}); /* Make the record button red */ } });`
That way you don't have to do repetitive if statements. Please note that buttonid would be returned as text by now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27712/discussion-between-ignacio-belhot-colistro-and-jl-griffin)

Comment: i did replay in chat with a few questions if you could check there. thnks!

Comment: Ignacio Please check the chat, i am still having problems with the script as i cant seem to get it to behave as it should thank you!